# Constant graph for Lasso and Ridge Regression

Tags: r, graph, regression, analytics, lasso-regression

I plotted the graph for log(Lambda) and Mean squared error and it looks like a constant line, which means MSE remains constant with increasing Log of Lambda. I have never seen this before. My data was small(14 variables out of which 13 were binary variables)and there were very less significant ones.My mse is 140. Specifically , i am not sure if this graph is normal to have.

Comment: are you sure you just called `plot(::my cv.glmnet object::)` ?

Comment: Here is my code:  Lassofit = cv.glmnet(data.matrix(Data[,-1]),data.matrix(Data[,1]), alpha = 1)
plot(Lassofit)